# MSB8004: Output directory does not end with a trailing slash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, compiler-warnings

I get this warning message on VS2010 SP1 building a C++ project. Configuration properties are:

Output Directory under General: $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\

Output File under linker: $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)

I tried changing these two properties but still get the MSB8004 warning.

Comment: Where is the solution directory located? How long is your path?

Comment: outDir: c:\tfs\main\abcdefghijkl\abcdef\abc\abcdefghijklm\abcdef\abc\Debug\ (68 chars). solution dir: c:\tfs\main\abcdefghijkl\abcdef\abc\abcdefghijklm\

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restart visual Studio & rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Open the project settings and add a `\` at the end of the Output Directory.
It should have a value like `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`

For more details refer to
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534031/erroneous-warning-msb8004

Comment: Link is dead. Archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20130917031619/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534031/erroneous-warning-msb8004